# linuux - execvp : On executing ls command - get error " ls: cannot access /etc : No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, exec, fork

The below function takes in a array of char pointers Eg : 
arr[0]: ls
arr[1]: -l
arr[2]: -a
arr[3]: /etc
arr[4]:NULL /* Since execvp expects a NULL at the end */

// `function call is runCmd(arr);`
the function definition is below :

```
void runCmd(char *arr[]){

        pid_t child_pid,tpid;
        int child_status;

        child_pid = fork();

        if(child_pid == 0){

                /* The child process executes the exec*/

                execvp(arr[0],arr);

                /*if it returns it must have failed */
                fflush(stdout);
                printf("Unknown Command \n");
                exit(0);
        }
                else {
                /*  let the parent wait for the child */
                do{
                         tpid = wait(&child_status);
                }while(tpid != child_pid);
        }
}
```

After executing I get the message -

```
ls: cannot access /etc
: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I added


    main()
    {
            char * rgs[] = {"ls", "-l", "-a", "/etc", NULL};
            runCmd(rgs);
    }

AND ran it on Linux.  Worked fine.  Post more code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you are reading in the command and forgetting to strip the trailing newline, causing your `ls` to try and list the directory `"/etc\n"`.